# php delete file and record when form submits

Tags: php, html, mysql, delete-row, delete-file

I have a form which deletes a record from mySQL database. This database contains the image/file name.

How do I add into the statement to also delete the file in the website directory with the same image/file name.

```
if ((isset($_POST['file_name'])) && ($_POST['file_name'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM image_carousel WHERE image_name=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_name'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_attibfn, $attibfn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $attibfn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: use `unlink(FILE_PATH)`

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: The answers below are correct but first you need to check the  file_name var to remove any folder information like ../../ then add the path where the image should be, check if the image exists and finally use unlink to remove it

Comment: I have an entire site setup with mysql_* functions. Any idea on a way of simply converting this??

Comment: you might start by introducing some DB independent wrapper functions and then replace it within the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use [unlink function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php):

```
unlink('/path/of/your/image/');
```

In your code:

```
if ((isset($_POST['file_name'])) && ($_POST['file_name'] != "")) {
$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM image_carousel WHERE image_name=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_name'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_attibfn, $attibfn);
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $attibfn) or die(mysql_error());

unlink('/path/'.$_POST['file_name']); // remove the image
}
```

Comment: Where and how should I place it in my statement

Comment: DO NOT trust user input blindly like this. It is a HUGE security vulnerability. If you followed this answer, you could realistically delete any file on the system this script is running on that the user running the script has permissions to delete.

Comment: I know, but he doesn`t care by now about it, he wants knows WHERE put that thing xD

Answer (score 2):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php `unlink($filename);`.

You will probably want to get the filename from the database, and validate it's existance. DO NOT blindly trust the user input.

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php `file_exists($filename)` to check if it exists.

So, you end logic should be something like:

- if a filename is submitted, and it's not empty
- then check the filename is in the database
- then check the file exists
- then delete the file
- then delete the row from the database for the file

Something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['file_name']) && !empty($_POST['file_name'])) {
  mysql_select_db($database_attibfn, $attibfn);

  $select = ""; // select filename query
  $filename = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());

  if (!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) {
    // Handle it! Throw an exception or something
  }

  unlink($filename);

  $deleteSQL = sprintf(
    "DELETE FROM image_carousel WHERE image_name=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_name'], "text")
  );

  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $attibfn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Also, consider using PDO, or at the least - MySQLi.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and being removed. They are insecure.

Comment: I would probably avoid using another query - mysql_affected_rows() after the delete query is a good enough indicator if there was such record

Comment: @Seer I have an entire site setup with mysql_* functions. Any idea on a way of simply converting this?? –

Comment: @dobromir-velev I dont quite get your answer! Im still new to PHP

Comment: @cedricrademan As suggested in a comment on your question, you could make a wrapper class that encapsulates the behaviour of the database (i.e. handles running queries, taking the parameters for queries, that sort of thing), and then use that instead. Gradually replace the mysql_* calls with your wrapper, then you can change your wrapper to use a different underlying technology, like PDO, or MySQLi

Comment: @cedricrademan you can create replacement functions like myquery($sql,$db) that just calls mysql_query($sql,$db), then replace all references to mysql_query with myquery and the you can easily change myquery to use PDO or mysqli to do the same thing. You should do this to all MySQL functions you use like mysql_fetch_row, mysql_connect etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ((isset($_POST['file_name'])) && ($_POST['file_name'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM image_carousel WHERE image_name=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_name'], "text"));
//delete file
unlink(<absolute path>/<filename>);
  mysql_select_db($database_attibfn, $attibfn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $attibfn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((isset($_POST['file_name'])) && ($_POST['file_name'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM image_carousel WHERE image_name=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_name'], "text"));

 unlink('/path/to/your/image/folder/'.$_POST['file_name']);    

  mysql_select_db($database_attibfn, $attibfn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $attibfn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: you should really check if $_POST['file_name'] is not something like ../../some.important.file